# Retrieving data appended to formData in C#

Tags: c#, jquery

In this scenario:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0]);
fd.append("PhoneId", '1234');
xhr.open("POST", '/Main/Upload', true);
xhr.send(fd);
xhr.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    var test = event.target.response;
})
```

I have a file upload along with an integer attached. My controller is:

```
 public ActionResult Upload(Model newModel)
    {
        NewFiles files = new NewFiles ();
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {}
    }

public class newModel
{
    public int FileID { get; set; }

    public string ReturnAction { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload { get; set; }

    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
}
```

The uploaded file gets recognized, but what do I need in C# to view the uploaded PhoneId?

Comment: use `Request.PhoneId`  OR  `Request.PhoneId[0]`

Comment: it says HttpRequestBase doesn't contain a definition for PhoneId

Comment: Shouldn't that be passed in `newModel` ?

Comment: it should, its in the viewmodel

Comment: can you print `newModel` and show us what is there? I am not a c#  developer. but that help others to find-out the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off in the controller and won't compile. Changing the controller to the following syntax should work. This shows how to access the POSTed file and the model properties.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(newModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Check the file is valid.
        if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            ModelState.AddModelError("fileUpload", "Invalid file uploaded.");

        // Access model properties as you wish, like this:
        int phoneID = model.PhoneId;

        return null;
    }
```

A couple of extra things to improve your code:

- Generally speaking, when defining a class, the name of it should be in the format of CapitalizeEachWord.
- It would be a lot easier if you used jQuery for your AJAX request rather than the normal JavaScript way of doing it. By using the normal JavaScript way, you're having to manually assign form properties to a FormData object, wheras with jQuery you can simpily do $("#formID").serialize().

Answer (score 0):

it will work

```
 string phoneId = Request.Form.Get("PhoneId");
```